# why is an HTML element modenizer created ?

Tags: javascript, html

i saw the following code in modenizer a few days ago and i was quite curious to know , why such a thing is done , have a look :

```
mod = 'modernizr',
modElem = document.createElement(mod),
mStyle = modElem.style,
```

now in HTML there is no element called `modernizr` , so why would you create such a element in the first place , this is done right at the top of modenizer, in the global declaration .

Why is such a thing done in modenizer ? whats the specific purpose ?

if you dig deeper in modenizer , you'll see that mStyle gets used as follows , in certain functions :

```
function testProps( props, prefixed ) {
    for ( var i in props ) {
        var prop = props[i];
        if ( !contains(prop, "-") && mStyle[prop] !== undefined ) {
            return prefixed == 'pfx' ? prop : true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

notice the check `mStyle[prop] !== undefined` .

so coming back to my question  , WHY create an element `modenizer` ?

Answer (score 1):

They are testing to see if the browser supports generation of [custom elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) and how many of the properties are generated when creating one